# too many ssh connections with java code?

Tags: java, ssh

I am having trouble with ssh connections in a piece of java code.

Here is the culprit code

```
public class ExecuteSecureShellCommand extends Object {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String [] machines = new String[] {machine0, machine1, machine2, machine3, machine4, machine5};

      ArrayList<Process> arr = new  ArrayList<Process>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
              for (String machine : machines){
                      String[] shell_connector = {"ssh", "-x", "msalem@"+machine, "echo ok"};

                      Process process=null;

                      ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(shell_connector);

                      process = builder.start();
                      arr.add(process);
              }
              try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }

      for (Process p: arr){
                    BufferedReader error_getter = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

                    String error_line = null;
                    while((error_line = error_getter.readLine()) != null)
                            System.out.println(error_line);
                    error_getter.close();
      }
  }
}
```

This code is for test purposes and has no meaningful results. But the thing is it causes the eror:
**ssh_exchange_identification connection closed by remote host**

FYI:

- the machines are sharing the same storage system (my local files on machines1 are the same on machine2)
- I ve generated an ssh key pair and am using it to connect
- I have no root access and therefore, I cannot change the limit of ssh connections number or anything else.

I want to know what is wrong with this code? 
What is the best way to perform a big number of ssh connections without failing?

In advance, thaks a lot for your answers!
Regards.

Comment: Does `ssh -x msalem@hostname echo ok` work from the command-line? If your Java program runs as a different user make sure you test the command as that user. Does this fail for every single host, or just some of them?

Comment: Does it works for `for loop` with 1 iteration?

Comment: Why do you need to run 1000 ssh connections at the same time? Cannot this be done in sequence?

Comment: @Mr.V. so for a loop with only 1, it does not fail. it seems to me that it starts failing when there are more iterations then the number of machines..

Comment: @JohnKugelman everything is ok with the commandline, and I am making sure to launch the scripts with my own user (same user actually)

Comment: @Thilo the idea is to do some iterations in parallel

Comment: if 1 is ok, try to find some limits 10 50 100 500 connections works ok? what OS is that? you can check configuration and find out max open connections available.

Comment: There is a difference between "some iterations in parallel" and "1000 connections". The latter will run into limits, not only on your machine, but also on the server and on the network. I cannot think more than, say ten, concurrent shells make much sense.

Comment: The os is redhat, limit seems to be random and the max open connections line is commented out in the sshd config file (I don't know if there is a default behaviour in this case...)

Comment: @thilo you mean if I need 1000 cnx I should rather start them by chunks of 10 parallel ssh sessions on the same machine, wait for their termination and then start other chunks of 10 parallel executions by machine?..

Comment: That would be the easiest. Ideally, you just keep re-using and multiplexing the pool of connections (if it's to the same target account). No need to tear down and rebuild connections all the time.